# Listing differnet kinds of an uncoutable noun. Are they countable or uncountable?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countability, singular-vs-plural, countable-nouns

How do you I refer to different kind of an uncountable noun? For example, this is a part of my writing:

> Using oil (coconut oil, olive oil) to moisturize your skin after bath. **Those** oil...

I want to explicitly refer to two kinds of oil to avoid other oil like engine oil mistakenly. Does *those* suit here? Are they countable? I think it's yes (look, I use *they* and *them* to refer to them in this sentence and the previous one). However, isn't that after using *those*, we should use the plural form of the noun? In that case, *oil**s***, not *oil*, should be use, right? And in that case, is *oil* a countable noun now?

Comment: Yes, because you are not counting *oil*, but *kinds/types of something* which happens to be oil in this example. But you better check your first sentence again - did you mean "use"?

Comment: @Stephie So I should use *those oils*, right? I thought to start a sentence with verb there are two options: *to verb* or *verb-ing*?

Comment: You could start with "using", but then this clause *needs continuing*, otherwise you are missing the verb: e.g. "(Using oil to moisturize...) is an effective way to...." This clause then becomes the subject of the sentence. - *those oils" is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a plural. In this case, you're no longer talking about oil itself but about two different *types/kinds/sorts of oil*. With this construction, the noun becomes countable and can be put in the plural.

So, you should say: **those oils**
Be sure not to forget the plural *s* after *oil* or your sentence will not be grammatically correct.